# Mocha tests for expressjs 4, spying on a function called in a promise, tests fail silently

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, mocha.js

I have some tests that look like this:

```
it('does stuff', function(done) {
  somePromise.then(function () {
    expect(someSpy).to.have.been.called
    done()
  })
})
```

If the assertion in that test fails, it will fail silently, and the test itself will timeout because `done()` is never reached. For example, this:

```
it('does stuff', function(done) {
  expect(1).to.equal(2)

  somePromise.then(function () {
    expect(someSpy).to.have.been.called
    done()
  })
})
```

will fail with a nice error explaining that we were expecting 1 but got 2. However, this:

```
it('does stuff', function(done) {
  somePromise.then(function () {
    expect(1).to.equal(2)

    expect(someSpy).to.have.been.called
    done()
  })
})
```

will fail due to timeout. I gather the issue is that I'm not in the "it" context, but what's the best way to deal with this?

Comment: What happens when you move the `done()` either outside and last of your `.then()` or outside and first?

Comment: If `done()` is outside of `then()` the test will finish before the promise resolves and the assertions are executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Failed assertions are basically thrown errors. You can `catch` them like you can any error in a Promise.

```
it('does stuff', function(done) {
  somePromise.then(function () {
    expect(1).to.equal(2)

    expect(someSpy).to.have.been.called
    done()
  })
  .catch(done)
})
```

Comment: That's it. I'm using mongoose promises, so I have to use `.onReject(errFunc)`, but this answers the question.